# Fourier series matlab

Tags: fourier-series, matlab

I have examples of Fourier series and I would using the Matlab I know how calculate the coefficients of Fourier series in Matlab

but how calculate the summation ? do I use “For loop “ or what in Matlab

Comment: Sorry, this question is not written in coherent English and as such it is unanswerable.  Can you please edit it to be more clear?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky sorry my language not good

Comment: Do you mean: you know how to make Fourier series using hand calculations.  You want to do those calculations using MATLAB instead.  You don't know how to use MATLAB to do that.  Is that right?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky I know how to use Matlab to calculate Fourier coefficients but to calculate F(x) I don’t know

Comment: I understand.  Do you use the fft function in MATLAB?  if you do, then you can use the "ifft" function.

Answer (score 0):

let $P$ be the period of your original function $F(x)$.  Let $F_N(x)$ be the function that is made from the first $N$ coefficients of the Fourier series. Then:

$$F_N(x) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^N\bigg[a_n\cos\bigg(\frac{2\pi n x}{P}\bigg)+b_n\sin\bigg(\frac{2\pi nx}{P}\bigg)\bigg]$$

Where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are your coefficients.

Let's say that you have two vectors in MATLAB named `an` and `bn`, and the period of the original function is stored in a variable `P`, and the point $x$ is stored in a variable `x`.  Then this should work:

```
n = 1:length(bn);
S = sin(2*pi*n*x/P);
C = cos(2*pi*n*x/P); %these intermediate variables make things easier
FNx = an(1) + an(2:end).*S + bn.*C; %assume that bn's length is 1 less than an
```

If you are using a different definition of $F_N(x)$ then the above code can be modified accordingly.  This should get you started.

Comment: what about for Fourier sine or cosine series ?